# Does Firebase Cloud Messaging work well on unreliable networks?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently using Firebase to send alerts from my server to android devices. It works when the user just connects to some networks for the first time and then stops working after. Until the user disconnects and reconnects again. Sometimes it doesn't. At other times, some devices receive the notifications and some don't.

Server Code

```
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$restKey = '';
$target_device = $token_array;  // using object Id of target Installation.
$push_payload = json_encode(array(
        "registration_ids" => $target_device,
        "priority" => 'high',
        "data" => array(
                "type" => $type,
                "is_background" => false
        )
));
$rest = curl_init();
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$push_payload);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("Authorization:key=" . $restKey,
                "Content-Type: application/json"));
$response = curl_exec($rest);
```

Android Code

```
    if ("request_response".equals(type)) {

        sendNotification("You have a response to your request", "Response Available", HomeActivity.class);

                    if (!BaseApp.isActivityVisible()){

                        sendNotification("You have a response to your request", "Response Available", HomeActivity.class);

                    } else {
    //process data
    }
```

Comment: The behavior for FCM is that it would send the message *as soon as feasible*. It'd try it's best. There might be a different reason why the notifications stops, I would advise checking if the token is being refreshed for some reason.

Comment: @AL.checked, it was never refreshed. Ended up giving up on FCM and using XMPP instead